# How should I make my code snippets not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-snippets

I am following this link(https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/snippet-guide) to develop the code snippet function of my vscode exetension.

I want my code snippets not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters. For example, "Enum"/"ENUM"/"enum"/"eNum"/"eNUm"/...and so on is all I need, how should I configure my "prefix" field（like using regex?）?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define multiple prefixes, choose the ones that are the most likely

```
{
  "Enum snip": {
    "prefix": ["enum", "ENUM", "Enum"],
    "body": ["MyEnum {}"],
    "description": "Enum foo bar."
  }
}
```

Or you can write a `CompletionItemProvider` and analyze the text before the cursor with a regex and create a snippet completion item.

Comment: Oh, that sounds like it means I can’t directly use regex in "prefix". Anyway, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @wugaoyin You can look at the HyperSnips extension how to match a regex prefix in a `CompletionItemProvider`

Comment: Your suggestion is very useful!! I will study HyperSnips extension right now in github. Thanks again and sorry for I can't cast a vote for your anwser because my reputation is less than 15.

Comment: @wugaoyin But you can accept this answer as the solution to the question

Comment: I just did this and thanks again~